# How can I convert a function to be a generic tempate

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function that I would like to use generics with I assume. Instead of the int[] in the function below, I would like the function to work with an array of pretty much any type (such as int[], double[], string[] etc..). How can I modify this code to do that?

```
    public static bool isHomogenous(int[] list)
    {
        bool result = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
            if (list[i] != list[0])
                result = false;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: that gives me "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic method signature.  By convention, the type specifier is prefixed with `T`.

```
public static bool isHomogenous<T>(T[] list)
{
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        if (!list[i].Equals(list[0]))
            result = false;
    return result;
}
```

Note that this treats the generic type `T` as an object if you don't constrain it with `where`, so you'll have to use the `.Equals` method to compare the values.

Alternatively, just use LINQ:

```
public static bool IsHomogenousLinq<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    //handle null and empty lists however you want (throw ArgEx?, return false?)
    var firstElement = list.First();
    return list.All(element => element.Equals(firstElement));
}
```

[Demo on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MpRTeD)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above also works but here is a shorter version:

```
public static bool IsHomogenous<T>(T[] list)
{
    return !list.Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
}
```